# mocking a QuerySet function

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I am creating testcases for a Django project where I am retrieving a value from an instance of a model.

For example,

```
instanceDog = models.Dog()
```

which leads to another model, `Tail`, and read by:

```
instanceDog.tail.all()[0].value
```

But in the unit-test, I can't seem to mock up the `all()` function.
Right now I have,

```
@mock.patch('path.to.code.models.Dog.all')
@mock.patch('path.to.code.models.Dog.objects.all')
@mock.patch('path.to.code.models.Tail.all')
@mock.patch('path.to.code.models.Tail.objects.all')
```

and if set to `mock_all`, used

```
mock_all.return_value = [models.Tail(value='value')]
```